# iterating through words in a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to abbreviate all words in a given string with the code below, however I can only get it to alter the first word of every string. What am I doing wrong?

```
function abbreviate(string) {
  var words = string.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 1) {
    var count = words[i].length - 2;
    var last = words[i].charAt(words[i].length - 1);
    return words[i][0] + count + last;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* You are `return`ing in the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

I think this solves your problem

```js
function abbreviate(string) {
    var words = string.split(" ");
    var answer = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 1) {

        var count = words[i].length - 2;
        var last = words[i].charAt(words[i].length - 1);
        answer= answer + words[i][0] + count + last;
    }
    return answer;
}
```